# tensorrt doesn't find argparse

Tags: tensorflow, tensorrt

I have installed tensorrt 3.0.4 but when I try to make an installation of tensorflow using tensorrt 3.0.4, I got the following:

```
uff 0.2.0 requires argparse>=1.4.0, which is not installed.
tensorrt 3.0.4 requires argparse>=1.4.0, which is not installed.
```

But the strangeness is that `pip show` argparse produce the following output:

```
Name: argparse
Version: 1.4.0
Summary: Python command-line parsing library
Home-page: https://github.com/ThomasWaldmann/argparse/

Author: Thomas Waldmann
Author-email: tw@waldmann-edv.de
License: Python Software Foundation License
Location: /root/env/py3/lib/python3.5/site-packages
Requires: 
Required-by: uff, tensorrt
```

Seems like `tensorrt` and `uff` can't find argpase, while they are also in `root/env/py3/lib/python3.5/site-packages`

```
$pip show tensorrt

Name: tensorrt
Version: 3.0.4
Summary: Python API for TensorRT, a high-performance deep learning inference optimizer and runtime for deep learning applications.
Home-page: https://developer.nvidia.com/tensorrt

Author: cudatools
Author-email: cudatools@nvidia.com
License: NVIDIA Software License
Location: /root/env/py3/lib/python3.5/site-packages
Requires: enum34, future, protobuf, argparse, numpy, pycuda, Flask, pillow
Required-by:
```

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved. Don't use a version of pip > 9.0.